# Should I add a language code in my HTML if I have just one language?

Tags: seo, google, html, local-seo, language

Should I do this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=en_US>
<head>
```

Instead of my current code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
```

If I only use just one language (meaning: my website is not multilingual). Would adding it now mean I'd e.g. decrease in ranks? For example, I have now a lot of users coming from different countries. Would adding this mean that my website will be ranked lower in those countries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the `lang` attribute in your `<html>` tag if you want to.  The [w3c recommends setting it](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-html-language-declarations).

If you do set it, you the value should just be `en`, not `en_US`.   It is a language identifier, not a locale identifier.  It should only specify the language, and not the language and country.

However, setting the `lang` doesn't actually do anything.  That attribute is not used in any way as far as I know.    [Google says that they ignore it](https://www.seroundtable.com/google-ignores-the-html-lang-attribute-22974.html) because they find it more reliable to detect the language from the words used rather than rely on meta-data.

Google uses `hreflang` tags to target alternate versions of your page to different languages.   See https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/189077?hl=en   However, if you only have one language, you shouldn't use hreflang tags.

If you do end up targeting your site to only the US, Google will not send traffic from other countries to your site.  If the traffic from other countries is valuable to you, you should not try to target your site to the US only.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So, let's ignore hreflang. But using 'lang' would not make a difference at all? Or would that also lead to a decline in traffic, as my site would only be served in the US?

Comment: It would be ignored by Google, so it wouldn't change your SEO.

Comment: Interesting. So it's actually pointless, from SEO perspective. Thanks, Stephen!